# Xamarin.Mac PdfView performance problems

Tags: macos, pdf, xamarin

I'm creating an app to visualize some experimental data (x,y plots with multiple series) where the primary goal is to generate a pdf file which conforms to scientific publication rules. The pdf generation works well and I can also display the pdf in a PdfKit PdfView. However, when I try to show large pdf files in the app (data series with lots of points (as in 20000)), some background thread will spend minutes (3-4) on generating some sort of cached version which the PdfView uses for faster zoom rendering.

I can get around the issue by setting the PdfView.Document as an empty pdf document and then adding a page afterwards. The PdfView will cache a blank page but I won't spend minutes at 100% CPU usage trying to generate a cached version. However, this introduced another issue, if there is no cached version, the zoom operation will be less pleasant than what is desired.

In addition, I have some sliders which affect the pdf result and the require very fast updates of the displayed pdf.

Is there a better way of displaying pdf files (data)? It would be best if the method allows zooming in the document.

Very slow for large pdf files:

```cs
PDFPlotView.Document = pdf;
```

Fast, but no cached version:

```cs
PDFPlotView.Document = new PdfDocument();

PDFPlotView.Document.InsertPage(pdf.GetPage(0), 0);
```

I've also tried generating a low res image from the pdf and then trying to use that image for cache generation, but it appears that there is a known bug which causes the pdf to become blank:

```cs
using (var context = new CGBitmapContext(null, (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height, 8, 0, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGBitmapFlags.NoneSkipLast)
{
    InterpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.None
})
{
    context.SetFillColor(new CGColor(1, 1, 1, 1));
    context.FillRect(rect);
    context.ScaleCTM(1, 1);
    context.DrawPDFPage(pdf.Document.GetPage(0));
    img = context.ToImage();
}

PdfDocument lowrespdf = new PdfDocument();
NSImage cache = new NSImage(img, rect.Size);
PdfPage page = new PdfPage(cache);

lowrespdf.InsertPage(page, 0);
```

[image: Example pdf file screenshot. The plot contains 25000 data points.]

> [UPDATE] Performance issue appears to be related not to the number of
>   data points, but rather to the length of a single path in the PDF file.
>   Splitting a problematic data series up in new lines every 1000 data
>   point results in a cache time of a few seconds (max) compared to a few
>   minutes for the 25000 data point line.

Comment: You can open it in WebView.

Comment: @frederiktheisen can you post a link to a sample PDF file that is rendered slowly?

Comment: Here is an example file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qje7GTY3gYj_azlSIdhZyIa1SjN-uqIy
The file will also cause problems in default Mac viewers (be careful). Since the problem is also apparent in external viewers, fixing the PdfKit viewer problem will not fix the issue.
The whole pdf viewing experience is somewhat dubious. Removing the page at index 1 right after checking if the document has more than 1 page will also rarely throw a native exception complaining that the index is outside the array.